# Ubuntu 19.10 feels laggy in VMware yet Fedora doesn't

Tags: performance

I also asked this on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/ex9qy7/ubuntu_1910_feels_laggy_in_vmware_yet_fedora/). I'm trying to set up an Ubuntu VM on a Windows 10 host using VMware Player for software development purposes. This is just something I'm experimenting with as I own a macbook and I've already tried WSL.

I tried out several flavors of Ubuntu including Ubuntu itself, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntu Mate, Elementary OS, and finally Fedora just out of curiosity.

I find that using a decently spec'd PC (I use it for gaming, mostly), and measuring performance just by how responsive the UI feels (dragging/resizing windows), Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Kubuntu, and Fedora all feel great, fluid.

On the other hand, Ubuntu, Ubuntu Mate, and Elementary OS all feel sluggish. As I move windows I notice a low refresh rate on all three. Why is that? Ubuntu Mate is based off of Gnome 2, if I understand correctly. I am not sure what Elementary uses, but Ubuntu itself uses Gnome 3, but so does Fedora and I have no issues there.

For reasons that are not important, I would like to use Ubuntu here and would like to know if anyone has an idea of what I could modify in the settings to make it as fluid as the others. Thanks!

I should note all Ubuntu flavors are based off of 19.10. Fedora is the latest release, as well.

Btw, Lubuntu is really nice. I'd pick that over Ubuntu if the window manager let me snap windows like Gnome does.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It turns out although Fedora is also using Gnome 3, they are using Wayland instead of Xorg. I tried Gnome Wayland on Ubuntu and it feels smooth now.